# Envio de model junto com upload de arquivos

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma API web construída com ASP.NET WebAPI, tenho um model que referencia uma URI de um arquivo (por exemplo representando uma foto numa galeria de fotos, ou um produto num catalogo) e preciso enviar os dados pra API.

Com relação a fazer o upload do arquivo já consegui encontrar como isso é feito em WebAPI [no proprio site do asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data,-part-2), o problema é que o model binder padrão não funciona quando o formulário é enviado com `enctype=multipart/form-data`.

O que quero dizer é que tenho no controller um método com essa assinatura:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] Model model)
```

Se eu não enviar com `enctype=multipart/form-data` o model binder funciona e eu consigo recuperar os dados do model, mas não obtenho o arquivo. Se eu coloco  isso, eu recebo o arquivo mas o model binder lança uma exceção

> The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.
>
> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Model' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.

A única solução que pensei por enquanto foi basicamente enviar primeiro só o model numa requisição, depois em uma requisição separada enviar o arquivo e associar a URI no model.

Existe alguma forma de fazer as duas coisas ao mesmo tempo? Ou o mais comum mesmo é fazer realmente em dois passos, primeiro mandando o model e depois o arquivo?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei a versão que você está utilizando do Asp.Net, mas tente obter o arquivo pelo request:

```
   if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
   {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Files[0].FileName))
                {   
                   //ROTINA PARA VALIDAR E SALVAR O ARQUIVO
                }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar o enctype multipar/form-data sim, porém sua action não deve ter um método, você terá que fazer o tratamento dos valores na mão, através de um loop foreach em `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider.FormData.AllKeys`, caso seja necessário realmente mapear os dados do formulário para um objeto (model) você pode fazer isso usando Reflection

Veja se este link te ajuda:

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2